# how to force reverse geocoder to return English results in Android

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding

I need to reverse geocoding a location in android but sometimes geocoder don't return results in English and this has some problems for me.

now how I should force geocoder to returns English results?

thank you friends.

Comment: Have look at this [Answer][1] that might help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348604/language-code-in-google-maps-java-api-v3/10354677#10354677

Comment: @Y.S android doesn't have Map API 3, that link must be for JavaScript

Comment: @Y.S : my problem is in android not in web. do you have any way for android?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713507/english-instead-of-local-language-for-geocoder

Comment: @shayanpourvatan : really? so there is no way for android? Thank you bro :)

Comment: i don't think so but try Locale in constructor, maybe helped, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636098/how-to-obtain-language-independent-values-from-android-geocoder